# Proguard/Dexguard dontobfuscate Specific image folder in React Native

Tags: react-native, proguard, dexguard

I have a react native application in which I am using Dexguard. When I do the release build of the application none of the images is loading. I have the images kept in this folder

> ProjectRoot > src>assets>images

I have my android code in this folder,

> ProjectRoot > android > app>

Looks like Dexguard is obfuscating the images folder, how do I tell dexguard not to do it,
I tried adding,

```
-keepresourcefiles images/**
```

and

```
-keepresourcefiles src/assets/images/**
```

but this has no effect. how to do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Not a restrictive rule, but this works for me:

```
-keepresourcefiles res/**
-keepresources **
```